# PHP interpreter fails if component implements a VERY speicifcally named interface

Tags: php, dependency-injection, yii2-advanced-app, naming

runtime: macos big sur, air m1, docker with php8

I wanted to make a collection serializer injectable via yii2 config so that the container provides an interface for me to work with and this is what I wrote:

```php
interface ClaimStateFeeChargeCollectionSerializerInterface
{
    public function serialize(ClaimStateFeeChargeCollection $collection): string;
}
```

and

```php
class ClaimStateFeeChargeCollectionSerializer implements ClaimStateFeeChargeCollectionSerializerInterface
{
    // implementation
}
```

and the config is as follows:

```php
'components' => [
    'collectionUnloadSerializer' => [
            'class' => ClaimStateFeeChargeCollectionSerializer::class
        ]
]
```

the code for actually getting the dependency:

```php
Yii::$app->collectionUnloadSerializer->serialize($collection)
```

but then when I run the code yii throws an exception saying that the interface cannot be found:
[image]

however, when I rename the interface to absolutely anything else it works just fine

am I missing something? something completely not obvious?

UPD: apparently, nothing breaks in php7.2
UPD2: I tried every version from 7.2 to 8 and in all of them the code worked; so I guess the issue is resolved but if you still encounter this or know why this happened - please leave a reply;

Comment: why don't you give it another name then? :D

Comment: @Armando I would really like to but thats the only one that is descriptive and accurate enough for this use case :(

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I'd advise you to set a max amount of time you'll put into this problem, and if you cannot fix it by then, pick another name and move on.

Comment: @Armando I updated my question so its not just about the name now, there's something funky going on with php

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this code in php7.2 but that forced me to run `composer update`

After this I run docker with php8 again and everything worked
I dont know what helped: updating composer or restarting the container, it may be both, but composer missing some classes to autoload seems like a reasonable reason for this issue